# Excel VB and XML Namespace naming convention

Tags: excel, xml

Assuming gfx is a root element in the below example, is xmlns:xsi and xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation considered attributes of the root, and if so how do they get assigned using Excel VB syntax? Using the code below the order in which they appear is reversed

```
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim rootAttrib1 As IXMLDOMAttribute, rootAttrib2 As IXMLDOMAttribute

    ' DECLARE ROOT AND CHILDREN '
    Set root = doc.createElement("gfx")
    doc.appendChild root
    
    Set rootAttrib1 = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:xsi")
    rootAttrib1.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    root.setAttributeNode rootAttrib1
    
    Set rootAttrib2 = doc.createAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation")
    rootAttrib2.Value = "Gfx-ME12.xsd"
    root.setAttributeNode rootAttrib2
```

Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gfx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Gfx-ME12.xsd">
```

Actual Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gfx xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Gfx-ME12.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of xml attributes does not matter.
In the xml infoset there is no such thing as an order of attributes.

Comment: thank you. ran my code and the parser on the other end seemed to accept it just fine